# einen Stein auf ihn/ auf ihn einen Stein

Tags: sentence-structure

Ich habe ein Problem mit der Satzbildung

Wie ist es richtig?

> Sie hat einen Stein auf ihn geworfen

oder

> Sie hat auf ihn einen Stein geworfen

Ist es dasselbe im Nebensatz?
Z.b.:

> Niemand weiß, wer auf ihn einen Stein geworfen hat.

oder

> Niemand weiß, wer einen Stein auf ihn geworfen hat.

Wie ist es in der Regel richtig?

Hängt es davon, ob es Dat. oder Akk. ist?

Comment: _"Sie hat auf ihn ..."_ ist mindestens nicht gebräuchlich, wenn nicht grammatikalisch falsch.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ist es das? Wieso? *Sie hat auf ihn einen Stein geworfen (und auf ihn ein Wattebäuschchen)*. Ich kann da keinerlei Fehler sehen.

Comment: @tofro Mit dem _und_ macht es wieder Sinn. Als alleinstehender Satz is es zumindest ungebräuchlich, bei _"grammatikalisch falsch"_ bin ich mir nicht sicher.

Answer (score 2):

Beides ist grammatikalisch korrekt und hat auch dieselbe Bedeutung. Die Wahl der Reihenfolge hängt von der Betonung ab und lässt sich im Zusammenhang besser erklären. Man sagt vielleicht das Betonte eher am Anfang des Satzes.
Beispiel:

> Sie warf einen Stein und kein Messer auf ihn.

Im Gegensatz dazu ein anderes Beispiel:

> Sie warf auf ihn und nicht auf sie einen Stein.

Comment: Die Zitatform ist generell besser zu lesen als die Backticks. Diese sind eigentlich zur Hervorhebung von Code gedacht, was hier i.d.R. nicht relevant sein dürfte.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Danke

Comment: Inwiefern hängt die Betonung von der Reihenfolge ab? M.E. kann man betonen was man möchte, wo immer es steht.

Comment: @userunknown: Kann man, ja, aber die meisten Leser würden es als Betonung sehen. Darum stellt man es "nach vorne". Beim Sprechen kann man ja noch Tonhöhe und Lautstärke zur Betonung benutzen.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Und worauf gründet sich diese Behauptung? Auf Hörensagen? Wunschdenken? Wenn Betonung nicht durch Auszeichnung dargestellt wird, kann man sie m.E. nur hören, oder sich beim Lesen einbilden.

Comment: @userunknown: Auf häufigem Sprachgebrauch. Das wird im Allgemeinen so gemacht. Man betont häufig etwas, indem man es "nach vorne" schiebt, sogar beim Sprechen. Noch nie gesehen oder gehört?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Häufig ist keine präzise Aussage. Die max. Abschwächung ist es dann zu fragen, ob ich das noch nie gehört habe, was überhaupt kein Argument gegen meine Behauptung ist, dass man überall im Satz betonen kann, also auch vorne. Da man beim Sprechen und hören die Sprache eigentlich so gut wie nie analysiert ist häufiger Sprachgebrauch auch kein geeigneter Maßstab. Ich habe keine Häufigkeitsanalyse gemacht - dass ich selbst das zu betonende nach vorne schiebe ist mir noch nicht aufgefallen und auch bei anderen nicht. Unsystematisches Beobachten führt aber leicht zu confirmation bias.

Comment: @userunknown _"Du bist aber auch eine harte Nuss!"_ vs. Yoda: _"Eine harte Nuss Du bist."_ :-D

Comment: @userunknown: weil ich nie bestritten habe, dass man überall im Satz betonen **kann**, verstehe ich deine Aufregung nicht. Ich (und wohl auch andere) haben beobachtet, dass man häufig das, was man betonen möchte, sooweit wie möglich an den Anfang des Satzes schiebt. Es tut mir leid, dass du das noch nicht beobachtet hast. Kommt aber häufig vor. Oh ja, "häufig" ist vielleicht ungenau, aber dadurch nicht weniger richtig. Inwiefern möchtest du eine "genauere" Aussage?

Comment: @userunknown: *confirmation bias*? LOL! Ich bin wohl nicht der einzige hier, der das beobachtet hat. Diese Antwort und die von πάντα ῥεῖ und Thorsten Dittmar deuten darauf wohl auch hin. Ich wundere mich nur, dass **du** das noch nicht beobachtet hast. So selten kommt das gar nicht vor.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Schön, wenn Du einräumst, dass man überall im Satz betonen kann, dann erübrigt sich ja das Argument, dass man ein Satzglied nach vorne schiebt, um es zu betonen. Das ist ja dann weder nötig, noch hinreichend. Wenn Du nicht erklären kannst, was "häufig" bedeutet, dann weißt Du offenbar nicht was Du sprachlich ausdrücken willst - das darfst Du mir nicht zum Vorwurf machen, der es nur verdeutlicht hat. Im genannten Beispiel geht es offenbar darum, dass ein Stein, kein Messer geworfen wurde. Er hätte also lauten müssen: `Einen Stein aber kein Messer warf sie auf ihn.` ...

Comment: Oder: `Einen Stein, kein Messer, warf sie auf ihn.`, nicht jedoch `und`, aber das nur am Rande. Aber zurück zur Positionierung. Wenn man an jeder Position im Satz betonen kann, wie kann man dann überhaupt zu dem Schluss kommen, dass ein Satzbau gewählt wurde, um eine bestimmte Betonung zu erzielen? `Sie warf auf ihn einen Stein, kein **Messer**!`. Man müsste schon sehr viele Sätze aufzeichnen und die Betonung darin finden. Sodann müsste man äquivalente Sätze mit anderer Betonung finden und auszählen und diese vergleichen mit unbetonten Sätzen aber gleicher Satzgliedfolge. Dann könnte man ...

Comment: sich streiten, ob die Daten signifikant sind, und 5% mehr Sätze mit der Betonung vorne vorliegen, oder 30% oder 66%, aber dazu müssten erst mal Daten vorliegen. Bisher liegt nichts vor, vage Grütze, ein Phantasie davon, was vorliegen würde, wenn man eine Untersuchung gemacht hätte. Gut, jetzt werden als Zeugen Petrus und Paulus angerufen, die das aus so empfinden, also auch keine Untersuchung kennen, aber das Gefühl teilen, dass eine Untersuchung solches zeigen würde. Grütze bleibt Grütze, auch wenn sie viele Esser findet.

Answer (score 1):

Weder

> > Sie hat auf ihn einen Stein geworfen

noch

> > Niemand weiß, wer auf ihn einen Stein geworfen hat.

hört/liest sich für mich gebräuchlich (an).

Es mag sein dass diese Formen etwas mit der gewünschten Betonung zu tun haben, aber ohne weiteren Kontext ist das schwer zu sagen.

---

> Wie ist es in der Regel richtig?

Ich würde sagen

> > Sie hat einen Stein auf ihn geworfen

und

> > Niemand weiß, wer einen Stein auf ihn geworfen hat.

---

> Hängt es davon, ob es Dat. oder Akk. ist?

Nein, die Wortstellung hat in diesem Fall nichts mit Dativ oder Akkusativ zu tun, sondern höchstens damit was betont werden soll. Aber wie gesagt, die zuerst genannten Formen sind nicht gebräuchlich, und nur im Kontext zu beurteilen.

Answer (score 0):

Alle diese Sätze sind grammatikalisch korrekt, aber sie setzen einen anderen Schwerpunkt:

> Sie hat einen Stein auf ihn geworfen.

Diese Variante wird überlicherweise verstanden werden, dass die Betonung auf dem Stein liegt. Einfach um klarzustellen, dass es keine Flasche oder Tomate war, sondern ganz klar ein Stein.

> Sie hat auf ihn einen Stein geworfen.

Diese Variante legt die Betonung auf "ihn". Man kann sich eine Situation vorstellen, wo mehrere Leute auf andere Steine geworfen haben und es geht darum, wer auf wen geworfen hat. Wenn man die Betonung mal durch Fettschrift hervorhebt, würde folgendes klären, auf welche Zielperson "sie" den Stein geworfen hat.

> **Sie** hat auf **ihn** einen Stein geworfen.

Alternativ kann die Betonung auch nur auf "ihn" liegen. Wenn sich einer beschwert, dass "sie" ihn mit einem Stein beworfen hat, "sie" aber auf jemand anderen geworfen hat, könnte die Antwort sein, dass der Vorwurf nicht stimmt, denn

> Sie hat auf **ihn** einen Stein geworfen.

Ähnliches gilt auch für die Nebensätze.

> Alle Personen wurden mit Steinen beworfen, aber niemand weiß, wer auf **ihn** einen Stein geworfen hat.

Oder aber:

> Er wurde mit vielen Gegenständen beworfen, aber niemand weiß, wer **einen Stein** auf ihn geworfen hat.

Answer (score -1):

Alle vier Satze sind grammatikalisch korrekt.

Die neutralste Reinfolge eines deutschen Hubtsatzes ist Nom. Verb Akk. Dat. Deutsch ist in Hauptsätzen SVO, mit extra V2.

So lang Verb und Nom. nebeneinander sind ist es grammatikalisch korrekt, jedoch linguistisch markiert.

> Auf ihn hat sie einen Stein geworfen.
>
> Einen Stein hat sie auf ihn geworfen.
>
> *Auf ihn hat einen Stein sie geworfen.
>
> *Einen Stein hat auf ihn sie geworfen.

In Nebensätzen ist Deutsch SOV. Deswegen ist auch in Nebensätzen die neutrale Aufstellung der Satzanteile Nom. Akk. Dat. Verb. In Nebensätzen ist die Aufstellung noch freier.

> Niemand wusste, dass...
>
> Sie auf ihn einen Stein geworfen hat.
>
> Auf ihn sie einen Stein geworfen hat.
>
> Auf ihn einen Stein sie geworfen hat.
>
> Einen Stein sie auf ihn geworfen hat.
>
> Einen Stein auf ihn sie geworfen hat.

Comment: "Die neutralste Reinfolge eines deutschen Hubtsatzes ist Nom. Verb Akk. Dat. Deutsch ist in Hauptsätzen SVO, mit extra V2." Kann man das auch in verständlichem Deutsch ausdrücken? Ich nehme an, dass der Fragesteller diese Terminologie auch nicht kennt (sonst müsste er wohl nicht fragen). Was ist übrigens ein *Hubtsatz*? *Hauptsatz* oder *Hubsatz*? Und wer "Einen Stein hat auf ihn sie geworfen" oder "Auf ihn hat einen Stein sie geworfen"  oder ähnliches schreibt muss wohl klein und grün sein oder einen an der Waffel haben.

Comment: In anderen Worten: bitte ohne zuviel "Fachchinesisch", wenn das eine brauchbare Antwort sein soll.

Comment: "So lang Verb und Nom. nebeneinander sind ist es grammatikalisch korrekt,". In ersten und zweiten Beispiel eines Hauptsatzes stehen sie nicht nebeneinander, da steht noch ein O dazwischen. Und trotzdem sind diese beiden Beispiele die "normalsten".